# Using application loader 2.4 to upload to the iOS app store

Tags: ios, xcode4, app-store, application-loader

I'm having trouble uploading an app to the app store using application loader 2.4 (The latest one). The problem is I don't know which file I should be uploading. It won't let me select the file produced when selecting product > archive or product > build.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

how far do you get after lauching application loader ? Steps should be something like: login with the itunes connect credentials, select deliver you app, select one of the eligible applications, select a binary, upload binary. Do you get any error messages (such as invalid binary, no eligible applications found, etc.) ?

Comment: I get as far as the "Deliver your app" screen. When I click choose, all file names are in tray (un-selectable).

Comment: What i am doing, is building the app, then zipping it, and it works for me. I never tried with .ipa format (resulting from Archiving). Try using zip and let me know if you succeded.